# Can't convert complex svg to canvas (and download)

Tags: canvas, svg

I'm using rickshaw.js to generate graphs on the clientside. Additional css file is used to specify the look. The generated graph is a svg. I want to provide a button to save the graph as png/jpeg etc.
I tried several solutions:

- using canvg to format svg to canvas and then to further formattings (http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/130-save-raphael-svg-chart-as-image)
- using a script provided by spin.atomicobject
- convert the svg to dataUrl and pass it to an image-tag (http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image/)

Here one of my solutions:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
            var svg = $('#rickshaw_graphic_svg')[0].outerHTML;
            canvg($('#myCanvas'), svg);

        });
```

But always the same error (indepedant of the chosen solution): the canvas (or the downloaded file) is completely black. But if I try to convert a simplier svg like a y-axis, it works (css ist not correctly formatted). So what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the librarys. Because of a grid which has no "fill"-atrribute, the whole canvas was black.